# I want to fetch an questions by id and it has multiple answers

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have Question model that has many answers

```
class Question extends Model
{
    public function answers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Answer');
    }
}
```

also I have Answer model , in this each answer belong to a question.

```
class Answer extends Model
{
    //
    public function question()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Question');
    }

}
```

So what i am trying to do is I want to fetch a question by it's id and it should have all the answers that belong to this particular question and together I want to pass it to my view.

Here is what I have Done so far

```
 public function show($id)
    {
      $questions = Question::with('questions')
                           ->join('answers', 'answers.question_id' , '=' , $id)
                           ->select('questions.id', 
                                        'questions.ask_question',
                                        'answers.user_id',
                                        'answers.aanswer',
                                        'answers.created_at')
                           ->where('questions.id' , '=', 'answers.question_id')
                           ->get();



return view('pages.show', ['questions' => $questions , 'user' => Auth::user()]);
    }
```

I have tried several other way but that didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just fetch the question and use the relation in the view.

```
public function show($id)
{
     $question = Question::find($id);
     if ( ! $question) {
         abort(404);
     }

     return view('pages.show', compact('question'));    
}
```

And in your model you can do something like:

```
<h2>{{ $question->question }}</h2>
<ul>
@foreach ($question->answers as $answer)
    <li>{{ $answer->answer }}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

---

Btw, there's no need to assign the `Auth::user()` to the view, the `Auth` facade is available there as well. You can also just use the helper method `auth()`.

```
<p>{{ Auth::user()->email }}</p>
```

or

```
<p>{{ auth()->user()->email }}</p>
```

Will work just fine.

Comment: Thank you Robert , That worked. I also want to know that in answers table there is a column user_id which is associated with id column in users table . How can i get user's name who have answered to particular question. Thanx

Comment: If you have the relations setup properly, you can just do `->user->name` on the answer model. But in that case check out the usage of `->with()`. This will eagerload the required models and also allows dot notation. This will save you a lot of queries :) Example: `Question::with('answers.user')->find($id);`